# Using Like Statement with IN

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a scenario where we are using multiple like statement in one of the query.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbyy0.png)

**SQL 2:**

```
 SELECT *
    FROM VOUCHER
    WHERE VCHTYPE = 'R'
   AND REMARKS  LIKE '%3791%'
 AND Remarks  LIKE '%3727%'
```

The thing is SQL 2 is getting it's input from SQL 1:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM VOUCHER
    WHERE VCHTYPE = 'D'
```

which changes every time.

We are trying to automate everything and want to modify SQL 2 in a way,so that input for SQL 2 can be taken directly from SQL 1.

I have attached the screenshot.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKkEw.png)

Kindly Help.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want `in`?

```
SELECT v.*
FROM VOUCHER v
WHERE v.VCHTYPE = 'D' AND
      v.vchseq IN (SELECT v2.vchseq
                   FROM VOUCHER v2
                   WHERE v2.VCHTYPE = 'R'
                  );
```

Comment: But I want to remove the LIKE statement and it should get the input from SQL 1

Comment: @Mam1004 . . . Then remove the `LIKE` from the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try a join along the lines of

```
select * from voucher a
join voucher b on
    (b.vchtype = 'D' and a.remarks like ('%' + b.vchseq + '%') and a.vchtype = 'R')
```

Comment: This one is not working for me. I have already  tried this one.It is throwing error.